# Any alternative for .net MS Chart?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, mschart

I am using MS chart for showing statical data in graphical way. Its .net framework 3.5 VS2008. At the initial stage i thought its easy and i implemented it .But we have so many JS libraries and modern day things ..is there any better way to do it...Code snippet as below

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="btnFindXcell" runat="server" Text="Create Chart" OnClick="btnFindXcell_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:GridView ID="dgvEmployee" runat="server">
                    </asp:GridView>
                    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Width="800px">
                        <series>
                             <asp:Series Name="Series1"></asp:Series>
                        </series>
                        <chartareas>
                        <asp:ChartArea BorderDashStyle="Solid" Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                        </chartareas>
                    </asp:Chart>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

using System;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using Excel;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Drawing;


public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Color color;
    private int b;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void btnFindXcell_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string path = Server.MapPath(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xmlPath"]);
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            //dt = FileUploadExcel(path);
            ds = ImportExcelXLS(path, true);
            dgvEmployee.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            dgvEmployee.DataBind();
        }
        //LoadChartCurrencyTotal(ds.Tables[0]);
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Column;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].Color = Random();
        Chart1.Series["Series1"]["DrawingStyle"] = "Emboss";
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        Chart1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = "Name";
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = "ID";
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.String;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
        Chart1.Series["Series1"].LabelForeColor = Color.Black;


        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = 1;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.LineColor = Color.DarkGray;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.LineColor = Color.Pink;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Azure;
        Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Peru;
        Chart1.BorderlineColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
        Chart1.DataBind();

    }

    public Color Random()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        b = r.Next(1, 5);
        switch (b)
        {
            case 1:
                {
                    color = Color.SeaGreen;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                {
                    color = Color.SlateGray;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                {
                    color = Color.SkyBlue;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                {
                    color = Color.SteelBlue;
                }
                break;
        }

        return color;
    }
    public static DataSet ImportExcelXLS(string FileName, bool hasHeaders)
    {
        string HDR = hasHeaders ? "Yes" : "No";
        string strConn;
        if (FileName.Substring(FileName.LastIndexOf('.')).ToLower() == ".xlsx")
            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";
        else
            strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=" + HDR + ";IMEX=0\"";

        DataSet output = new DataSet();

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            DataTable schemaTable = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(
                OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });

            foreach (DataRow schemaRow in schemaTable.Rows)
            {
                string sheet = schemaRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

                if (!sheet.EndsWith("_"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet + "]", conn);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                        DataTable outputTable = new DataTable(sheet);
                        output.Tables.Add(outputTable);
                        new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(outputTable);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(ex.Message + string.Format("Sheet:{0}.File:F{1}", sheet, FileName), ex);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
    public DataTable FileUploadExcel(string filepath)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        System.IO.FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filepath);
        string FileExtension = fi.Extension;
        FileStream stream = File.Open(filepath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        IExcelDataReader excelReader;
        if (FileExtension == ".xls")
        {
            //1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
            excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
        }
        else
        {
            //2. Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
            excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
        }
        excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
        if (excelReader.AsDataSet().Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            dt = excelReader.AsDataSet().Tables[0];
        }
        return dt;
    }

}
```

Its for testing purpose reading data from a excel file and create chart based on data ..

Comment: I"m not sure I understand the question.  There isnt any problem w/ the code, you just want a recommendation for a better tool/technology?

Comment: @paqogomez .Thanks for replying ...Its working fine ...I want to fit the above code with some better technologies ..I just read ...http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/javascript-graphs-and-charts-libraries ..and thought highchart would be a better option

Answer (score 1):

One of the most widely used chart library of current time is [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/). I highly recommend it, its easy to use highly customizable with rich features and user experience.

Comment: Thanks dude ...but i don't know how to integrate it with asp.net ..can you please give and example for my code snippet

Answer (score 0):

There lot of jquery chart 
some highly used are are follow

1. **[JsCharts](http://www.jscharts.com/examples)**
2. **[jQuery Visualize Plugin](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/)** - [Exapmles](http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/jqueryui-visualize/)
3. **[Highchart](http://www.highcharts.com/)**
4. **[Flot](http://www.flotcharts.org/)**   -  [Examples](http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/)
5. **[jqPlot](http://www.jqplot.com/)**  [Examples](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/)
6. **[Chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/)**

Comment: @satindar Thanks for your answer..can you please help me with some asp.net code snippet..i have done it with MS chart for a testing purpose ...can we do the same with highcharts

Comment: @RahulChowdhury: theres  lot of sample available, mostly client side  so you need to play with you data generate xml/array and use any of above jquery chart plugin to dispaly your data, Read documentation for better understanding of particular Jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at:

[ZedGraph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/) This object is implemented as both a UserControl and WebControl. Integrating it into ASP.NET is covered by [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5431/A-flexible-charting-library-for-NET).

[Google Visualization](https://developers.google.com/chart/) This is a javascript library that can be integrated onto any web page. Google has a good [Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/index) page that will show you what to do.